# Correct usage of junit-toolbox MultithreadingTester

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

*Background*

I have read the documentation for the `MultithreadingTester` provided in  [junit-toolbox](https://junit-toolbox.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/googlecode/junittoolbox/MultithreadingTester.html) and still don't entirely grok if I'm using it correctly.

How I would expect it to work:

```
MultithreadingTester.add(callable1, callable2)
  // validate my results from running callable1 and callable2
  .run();
```

Where `callable1` and `callable2` would be executed and then I could verify the results ... then the `MultithreadingTester` would run the two callables again ... and once again I'd verify the results.

From what I've put together my expectations are misaligned with what's provided.

*Question*

Does someone have a simple example of using the MultithreadingTester to validate a synchronized code path?

Comment: Note, for what it's worth, this isn't a Google project but something someone posted on Google Code: https://github.com/michaeltamm/junit-toolbox

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't know how I missed that.  Updated the question to reflect this.